# In an excel range object the .Value2 is returning an error 2015. The cell data is linked to the google finance stock names

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a different property (if that is the right term) to use instead of .Value2 that will return the value that is in the cell ie:  Core S&P 500 Idx ETF (CAD-Hdg) (XTSE:XSP)?  Tks.

```
For w = 1 To WS_Count
 With wb.Worksheets(w)
    arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value2
    Debug.Print arr(1, 1) ' 23.1 which is C2
    Debug.Print arr(2, 1) '     which is C3 (column, row format)
    'dict.RemoveAll

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)  ' Loop through and assign to dict.
        k = arr(i, 1)               'the key
        amt = arr(i, 2)             'the amount
        dict(k) = dict(k) + amt     'sum amount for this key
    Next i
```

'''

Comment: `.Formula` perhaps? You might have to get a bit more creative with creating `arr`.

Comment: OH yes,  I thought that formula would actually return the formula not the value. I just tried it. and that worked.  sorry. and thank you

Comment: No need to be sorry, I'm honestly not sure what the best way to do this is. You can check if a cell [`.HasRichDataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasrichdatatype), or its [`.LinkedDataTypeState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.linkeddatatypestate), but those aren't quite what you want here. Apparently `.Formula` works but there may be another option.

Comment: Yes, and I will have to check if the next column will work as it is a "number value" already